# RequireJS using Sugar Syntax?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js, syntactic-sugar

I know that requireJS supports sugar syntax, is the following code correct to load the module located at js/window/startup.js, with the dependencies of jquery, underscore, and Backbone?

```
require.config({
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost/js/',
  path: {
    jquery: '/lib/jquery-1.9.1.min',
    underscore: '/lib/underscore-1.4.4',
    backbone: '/lib/backbone-1.0'
  }
});

require([
  './window/startup',
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
], function(Startup){
  Startup.init();
});
```

The code in js/window/startup.js:

```
define(function (require) {
  var $ = require('jquery');
      _ = require('underscore');
      Backbone = require('backbone');

  //Test to see if module is being fired
  console.log('The module code has been executed!');

  var init = function(){
    /* SOME CODE */
    //Test to see if the init function has fired
    console.log('The initialize function has fired!');
  }

  return {
    init: init
  }

});
```

It all seems to conform to the documentation, yet when I run this code, neither of the two console messages are displayed.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up - wrote this on the fly.  Still hasn't resolved the error though...

Comment: I've made an answer below highlighting the various errors you have in your code.

Comment: Just a quick tip: If you'd like to use the CommonJS syntax all the way instead of wrapping your modules in define(...), check out cajon - https://github.com/requirejs/cajon

Answer (score 2):

You've got a bunch of syntax errors spread throughout your code. Check out [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OiPdZXuVvTtXayI9QriQ?p=preview) for a working example.

Here's what you've gotten incorrect:

```
require.config({                         // NEED PARENTHESIS HERE
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost/js/',
  paths: {                               // SHOULD BE paths, NOT path
    jquery: '/lib/jquery-1.9.1.min',
    underscore: '/lib/underscore-1.4.4',
    backbone: '/lib/backbone-1.0'
  }
});                                      // NEED END PARENTHESIS HERE

require([
  './window/startup',
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone'                             // GET RID OF TRAILING COMMA
], function(Startup){
  Startup.init();
});
```

And in your other file:

```
define(function (require) {              // GET RID OF EXTRA PARENTHESIS IN HERE
  var $ = require('jquery'),             // SHOULD BE COMMA, NOT SEMICOLON
      _ = require('underscore'),         // SHOULD BE COMMA, NOT SEMICOLON
      Backbone = require('backbone');

  //Test to see if module is being fired
  console.log('The module code has been executed!');

  var init = function(){                 // NEED AN ASSIGNMENT, INSTEAD OF JUST var fn() {}
    /* SOME CODE */
    //Test to see if the init function has fired
    console.log('The initialize function has fired!');
  };

  return {
    init: init
  };

});                                      // NEED END PARENTHESIS HERE
```

I would strongly suggest using a code editor that reports syntax errors. This would help you avoid problems like these.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the syntax errors, but they aren't the root of the problem - even with them fixed, the code still does not work.

Comment: Have you compared your code to the example plunker I linked to in the answer? It is working. . . .

Comment: Yes, sadly no dice :(